# Race condition in Angular between vm.init and dropdown options

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a C# MVC project, using Angular in the views.  The project has a custom dropdown control implemented through a directive.  The view's JavaScript controller is `BuildingController`, which in turn has a service `RoomManager`.

The view sets up the `Building` controller by calling `data-ng-init="vm.init('@Model.Id')`.  Internally, `Building.init` calls `this.RoomManager.init(id)`, which returns a promise.  (`ID` is the same, passed down to `RoomManager`.)  That in turn caches the building and room request, including a list of `Rooms` as `Array<any>`.

The view also sets up the dropdown control's list (implemented as a `<UL>` element) with a database-defined list of selection reasons, through `data-ng-init="vm.RoomManager.reasonInit('@ViewBag.ReasonId')"`.  This queries the data store, then populates the `RoomManager.Reasons` data member as another `Array<any>`.  Then the dropdown control sets its options with `options="vm.RoomManager.Reasons"`.

Sometimes this all runs correctly; sometimes the dropdown control has the correct number of rows in its list, but the values are all incorrectly blank.  I placed breakpoints in the JavaScript debugger in the web browser, and have observed the following:

- When `reasonInit` fires *before* the dropdown control is rendered, the control's list is correctly populated.
- When `reasonInit` fires *after* the dropdown control is rendered, the control's list is incorrect.
- When the reason ID is passed through the `init()` methods into the `RoomManager`'s promise, the control's list is **always** incorrect.

There's almost certainly a race condition here.  But I have no idea how to resolve it, to make the `RoomManager.reasonInit()` method fire at the proper time or to defer the dropdown directive's rendering.

Comment: Why aren't you putting all these promises in the resolves for ui-router or something like that? Also, having a method like init() is great, but controllers have one called $onInit() for this very purpose.

Comment: @rrd: Because that's how it's presently written.  I know that's not a good answer to your question, and it may be worth my time to research a good answer.